# How to make a POST Request in Flutter to send an mp4 file? (Without non-core APIs)

Tags: flutter, dart, file-upload, httprequest, multipartform-data

I want to understand and know how to make a multiPart request with an mp4 file attached. While I understand there are posts that speak of dependencies such as ***dio*** or ***flutter_upload*** to do this, I don't want to cheat myself in knowing the *why* of things. So how do I accomplish this task? I keep getting the following error when making a request:

**Error Snippet**:

```
flutter: Failed due to: Unsupported Media Type and status code: 415
```

My endpoint only accepts **Content-Types** of **application/JSON**, but my app still threw when I tried to refactor my request to send json. I understand Dart requires data to be encoded before making a request but I am confused about how I do this with a `MultipartFile` instance when I get the following error:  `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MultipartFile'`. Finally, I refactored my function to reflect my latest attempt to send the correct format (despite no encoding involved :D).

**Code Snippet**:

```
Future<void> createAudioUpload(String fileUrl) async {
  Uri ourUri = Uri.parse(
      'https://[redacted]');
  final request =
      http.MultipartRequest('POST', ourUri); // creates our req instance

  final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('audio', fileUrl,
      contentType: MediaType('audio', 'mp4')); // points a ref to file

  request.files.add(file); // adds our file to our request instance
  final response = await request.send(); // sends our request to the endpoint!

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('Success, $response');
  } else {
    print('Failed due to:${response.reasonPhrase}');
  }
}
```

Code Snippet V2: (sending data as bytes)

```
Future<void> createAudioUpload(String fileUrl) async {
  Uri ourUri = Uri.parse(
      '[redacted]');
  final request =
      http.MultipartRequest('POST', ourUri); // creates our req instance

  File ourFile = File(fileUrl);
  List<int> fileBytes = ourFile.readAsBytesSync();
  // String base64File = base64Encode(fileBytes);

  final file = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('flutter_sound', fileBytes,
      filename: fileUrl.split("/").last,
      );

  request.files.add(file); // adds our file to our request instance
  final response = await request.send(); // sends our request to the endpoint!

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('Success, $response');
  } else {
    print('Failed due to: ${response.reasonPhrase} and status code: ${response.statusCode} ');
  }
}
```

**Questions I want to understand (after I referenced flutter docs)**:

1. What is supposed to be the first positional argument of  `MultipartFile.fromPath`
2. What is the correct syntax to pass for application/json? would the arguments be passed as `"application", "json"` for MIME main and sub type per the docs at https://pub.dev/documentation/http_parser/latest/http_parser/MediaType/MediaType.html ?

**Quick Note**

1. The data passes through an API gateway and is eventually stored in an S3 bucket.
2. I referenced https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html for constructing the code.
3. If there is known documentation how to convert the audio file to bytes before sending that is also great!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe you can use a multipart request as they will all have a `Content-Type` of `multipart/something` which you say your endpoint cannot accept. Is there anything wrong with just a normal POST request?

Comment: Hey Chris, when I submit a normal POST request without additional headers I still get the same error. I am looking to see if there can be some tweaks to what the endpoint receives instead.

Comment: Could you show the error and maybe edit your question to add the code to show what you tried to do?

Comment: The error code above is already included above for the status code of: 415. And I just added another snippet of my attempt to send data in byte format. The main point of confusion for me is knowing what to do with the **MultipartFile** constructor

Comment: What I meant in my first comment was to use the [`post`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html) function to send the data because using the multipart request will set the content-type to `multipart/something` which your endpoint then rejects with the expected 415. Using a post would allow send JSON data and set the correct headers. Could you elaborate on your confusion with the `MultipartFile` constructors? Or why you want to continue with them? The `fromPath` static method takes a *full* file path as its first argument and you're using the `fromBytes` constructor correctly.

Comment: Awesome! I just realized what you said. After implementing your observation I deviated from submitting an instance of Multipart form to submitting the byte formatted audio wrapped in JSON. The bucket confirmed with a 200 response and my audio file was stored in the S3 bucket!

Comment: As to your question Chris, I was referencing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809222/flutter-http-request-upload-mp3-file and one other post when writing that code to accomplish my goal. I became so absorbed in finding the solution that I ignored my payload type did not match my endpoint to begin with.

For the downvote, if whoever could be so kind as to explain where my post is lacking so I may better format my questions in the future since I covered the issue, included snippets of my code and error. Thanks!

Comment: The only reason I could think of for the downvote is you have multiple question in a single post, which is discouraged and a reason your question could be closed. So something to be wary of. However, this is one of the few well-researched and well-described posts on the flutter tag so I upvoted to compensate for whoever downvoted you :). Based on how I led you to a solution in the comments, the downvoter might have also voted because the problem you describe is an [X-Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem, but I don't see that as a reason to downvote.